# Microsoft cognitive service port number

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

We are using Microsoft cognitive services (LUIS, QnA Maker, Bing web search) and Bot Service directline channel behind the corporate proxy.

Which port numbers are required to open in our corporate proxy for those services?
(like 1433 is required for Azure SQL service.)

Thanks!

Comment: The web services (LUIS, QnA maker, and Bing search) don't need port numbers. They are HTTPS calls.

Comment: Thank you! @DFBerry

Answer (score 1):

since Azure API using https protocol, you have to make sure that 443 port is open.